# Adding other fields including xvalue and yvalue on tooltip for LightningChart JS

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

I am adding the chart like this

```
 for (let tpName in tpGroupedData) {
      this.series = this.chartInstance
           .addPointSeries({ pointShape: shapes[shapeIndex], dataPattern: lsjs.DataPatterns.horizontalProgressive, xAxis: createdAxis })
           .setPointFillStyle((solidFill) => solidFill.setColor(lsjs.ColorHEX(palette.simpleSet[seriesColorIndex])))
           .setName(groupTag.slice(0, groupTag.indexOf('(')) + '( ' + tpName + ' )');

        for (let dataItem of tpGroupedData[tpName]) {
          this.series.add({ x: Date.parse(dataItem.testDateTime) - dateOrigin, y: dataItem.value })
        }
```

On tooltip I want to add other values of dataItem as well instead of just showing x and y coordinates

Answer (score 0):

You can show the data you want by setting the series' resultTableFormatter with a custom one.

You can do this by using a [TableContentBuilder](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.2.2/classes/tablecontentbuilder.html) like so:

```js
series.setResultTableFormatter((builder, series, segment) => {
  return builder
    .addRow(series.getName())
     // Get the data from the series X value, use formatting from Axis TickStrategy
    .addRow(series.axisX.formatValue(segment.getPosition()))
    // Add additional row. A single string will be centered horizontally in the resultTable.
    .addRow('Additional data: ' + dataToShow ))
    // Add additional row. Undefined or '' marks a gap, which will fill any extra space of row. Here the first string will be anchored to the left; third string is anchored to the right of the resultTable.
    .addRow('More data', undefined, dataToShow)
} )
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I want to show other items based on data instead of just name, xvalue and yvalue. The other values include dynamic data coming from backend. Is there any way to add values other than x and y and access them in setResultTableFormatter.

Comment: You can customize the resultTable rows as you want. If you want to show only data outside of the series, you'll just need to provide that data to the resultTableFormatter when you create it. The last two addRow() methods show this - you'll just need to provide the data in the addRow() methods. You can omit the series name, x and y values when creating the custom resultTable if they're not necessary in your application.